# Is there any particular benefit to deploying JBoss on a RHEL system?

Tags: jboss, application-server, rhel

I wouldn't expect so.  Is there anything to point out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The only thing I can think of offhand is that JBossAS comes with specific startup scripts for solaris, hp-ux, windows and redhat linux, but that's hardly enough to warrent influence - don't let it affect your choice of OS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [JBossWeb Native](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/native.html) is better tuned or tested on RHEL?  When I tried it on Solaris 10, it performed slightly worse than the all-java stack.